# How to obtain and use the .bbl file in my tex document for ArXiv submission?

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex, arxiv, bbl

I am submitting my first article to ArXiv and in the instructions they specify I have to include the `.bbl` file. Their instructions are:

"We do not run BibTeX in the auto-TeXing procedure. If you use it, include in your submission the `.bbl` file that BibTeX produces on your own machine; otherwise your references will not come out correctly. We do not run BibTeX because the `.bib` database files can be quite large, and the only thing necessary to resolve the references for a given paper is the `.bbl` file. The name of the `.bbl` file must match the name of the main `.tex` file for the system to process the references correctly."

My knowledge of LaTeX is basic, and I have not heard of `.bbl` file before. I am using TeXmaker. I have my `tex` file and my `bib` file. So what do I exactly do to obtain the `.bbf` file correctly and submit the article?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588430/no-bbl-file-for-submission-to-arxiv

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Start with an new directory.  Copy your file `mwe.tex` and `mwe.bib` inside it.

File `mwe.bib`:

```
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
```

File `mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref} % for better urls


\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mwe} % file mwe.bib

\end{document}
```

The trick is to **run** first `pdflatex mwe.tex`, suppose your tex code is `mwe.tex`.  Then you will see more files in the directory, important is the new file `mwe.auc`, containing several informations, for example the used (cited) bib entrys.

Now **run** (second) `bibtex mwe`. Check the directory again.  BiBTeX builds a new file, `mwe.bbl` and `mwe.blg`. In `mwe.blg` is the log file for the bibtex run, in `mwe.bbl` is that file you need for submitting.

Resulting file `mwe.bbl`:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{Goossens}
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin.
\newblock {\em The LaTeX Companion}.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, 1 edition, 1994.

\bibitem{adams}
Douglas Adams.
\newblock {\em The Restaurant at the End of the Universe}.
\newblock The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy. Pan Macmillan, 1980.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Now run (third) `pdflatex mwe.tex` **twice** to get a correct page numbering and ...

Now copy your file `mwe.tex` to `mwe-arxiv.tex` and delete the usage of `bibtex` to create the bibliography.

Insert instead the content of the `mwe.bbl` file.

New file `mwe-arxiv.tex` with included `mwe.bbl`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref} % for better urls


\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt} % <======================== not longer needed!
%\bibliography{\jobname} % <========================== not longer needed!
\begin{thebibliography}{1} % <================================== mwe.bbl

\bibitem{Goossens}
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin.
\newblock {\em The LaTeX Companion}.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, 1 edition, 1994.

\bibitem{adams}
Douglas Adams.
\newblock {\em The Restaurant at the End of the Universe}.
\newblock The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy. Pan Macmillan, 1980.

\end{thebibliography} % <======================================= mwe.bbl

\end{document}
```

Now you have **only** to submit **this** new file `mwe-arxiv.tex` ...

Or just use `\input{mwe.bbl}` (but please see I do not know if that is allowed by arxiv) but now see you have to submit **two** files (`mwe-arxiv.tex` and `mwe.bbl`).

New file `mwe-arxiv-input.tex` with `\input`ed `mwe.bbl`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref} % for better urls


\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt} % <======================== not longer needed!
%\bibliography{\jobname} % <========================== not longer needed!
\input{mwe.bbl} % <============================================= mwe.bbl

\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought it was sufficient to upload the `.bbl` and `.tex` as is after multiple compilations. All that arXiv needs is the `.bbl` so it doesn't have to run bibtex no?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to obtain the .bbl from .bib @Dan Brown

Comment: Ok, what is the directory for tex and where do I find it? @DaiBowen

Comment: Thank you, found it. I did not see it before because the directory was not showing all file name extensions by default. So I understand that I need to submit two separate files to ArXiV: one file "mypaper.tex" and another file" mypaper.bbl" ? @DaiBowen

Comment: @Casimir for the arXiv?  Yes, upload the `.bbl` as with the rest of the files to arXiv should in principle work **but** you will need to use the same version of `biblatex`/`biber` locally as is on the arXiv in order to generate a compatible `.bbl` file which could be problematic, although the arXiv has recently updated to a TeXLive 2016 installation.

Comment: @DaiBowen Turned out not to be an issue. BibLaTeX works fine with their new installation.

Comment: I don't understand from "delete the usage of bibtex to create the bibliography: \bibliograpgy{mwe.bib}" . Please explain more.

Comment: @HahaTTpro please see updated answer!

Comment: Can someone confirm whether `\input{mwe.bbl}` works?

Answer (score 83):

If you're using overleaf, you can simply click on the "Submission" Icon and select the "Arxiv" option, it will give you all the files you need.

Comment: This answer should show up on the IMO. Thanks a lot

Comment: Better answer than accepted one.

Comment: Not really. I popped it into this error coming from overleaf .zip prepared for arXiv...

Comment: I was scared when I read @Mensch answer, but relieved when I saw this!

Comment: Awesome! Took a few seconds - way faster than it would have taken to even read the accepted answer!

Comment: If you were using `.bib`, you need to unzip the folder and copy the contents of the `.bbl` file into the references of the `.tex`, in place of the `\bibliography` command. Basically, the .bbl file references are pasted in the .tex manuscript as one single file.

Comment: Seems "Submission: icon has been removed??

Answer (score 2):

I'm deciphering the `bibtex`/`pdflatex` pipeline in another context and the answer by user *Mensch* has helped a lot. As complement, a diagram of that particular work pipeline:

[image: The pdflatex bibtex work pipeline]