# Merging bib and tex files for submission to a journal

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, journal-publishing, combine

I am submitting an tex article to a journal, and they want they do not accept bib files. They also want only one source file:

1)A LaTeX submission should be a single .tex file; multiple-(.tex)-file submissions are not supported.
2)Uploading .bib files as Additional LaTeX file types is supported.

So this means I have to merge the bib and tex file into one, but I have no idea how to do this.

I looked at similar posts and people say use bbl. file and copy that into \bibliography... But I don't understand what this actually means.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd read "Uploading .bib files as Additional LaTeX file types is supported." as saying please upload one `tex` file and (if you use `bibtex`) one `bib` file, are you sure you need to merge them?

Comment: that means you can give them your tex file and a bib file, you must not merge them.

Comment: didn't you ask this a moment ago? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351455/combining-revtex-file-and-bib-file-into-one

Comment: Rather than uploading your bib file I would simply include the `bbl` file into your document (and comment out the `\bibliography{...}` line).

Comment: When you say "include bbl file", in practise what does this mean? How do I make the bbl file from bib ? Could you please provide a minimal working example of code incorporating this? @Andrew

Comment: The `bbl` file comes about as a by-product of running bibtex ([Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/106162) is the standard reference on this site).  I thought you were able to generate `bbl` files from your previous question [How to obtain and use the .bbl file in my tex document for ArXiv submission?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329198/106162)

Comment: By "include" the bbl file I mean copy and paste the bbl file into your TeX file. The bbl file is generated by bibtex. If your bibliography is displaying properly then you will find thew bbl in the same directory/folder as your main tex file (if your tex file is `file.tex` then the bbl file will be `file.bbl`).