# How to incorporate bibliography in the document using ShareLatex?

Tags: bibtex, sharelatex, bbl

I am using sharelatex to prepare a paper for submission to JASA. I got the paper looking nice using the LuaLaTeX compiler with very little warnings. However, I noticed on their submission guidelines that the authors have to submit a single **.tex** file:

> Note: JASA submission guidelines require that you submit a single TEX
>   file. Therefore, if using BibTEX, when you finally submit your paper
>   to the Journal, you must incorporate your bibliography directly in
>   your TEX document. Using a text editor, replace the \bibliography
>   statement with the contents of the generated .bbl file.

I have seen how to do this using [Latex](http://www.bibtex.org/Using/) compiler or [pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329198/how-to-obtain-and-use-the-bbl-file-in-my-tex-document-for-arxiv-submission) compiler. However, when I try to compile my document with this I get numerous errors. My question is: is there a way of generating the **.bbl** file using LuaLatex? I am using MS Windows and also have access to a working GNU box.

Comment: It's not LuaLaTeX that generates the `.bbl` file, it's `bibtex`. But ShareLaTeX runs `bibtex` for you automatically. It's not entirely clear to me what you've tried. If it worked before you replaced `\bibliography{..}` with the contents of the `.bbl`, it should work after as well. Or have you not been able to get the `.bbl` file from ShareLaTeX?

Comment: I have not been able to generate the .bbl file in sharelatex, at least i cannot find it! How can one access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bbl` file is generated automatically by ShareLaTeX, but not added to the file list. You can still access it though. This is assuming you have a working document with a bibliography.

Right next to the Recompile-button (above the preview), there is a button taking you to "logs and output files":

[image]

Then click on "other logs and files", and one of the choices should be `bbl file`.

[image]

Click to download the file. Open it in a text editor on your computer, and copy everything. Go back to ShareLaTeX, comment out/remove

```
\bibliographystyle{..}
\bibliography{..}
```

and paste the contents of the `.bbl` file right below `\bibliography{..}`.