# no .bbl file for submission to ArXiV

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, arxiv

I am trying to upload a preprint on ArXiV. However, I am getting the following message:

```
Your submission contained paper.bib and paper.tex file, but no paper.bbl file (include paper.bbl, or submit without paper.bib; and remember to verify references).
```

which does not let me to continue the submission process.

I have no files .bbl, but only a .bib file (as for the templates provided here: https://it.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/arxiv).

[image]

Do you know how I could fix it? Unfortunately I am not so familiar with LateX, especially with references and BibTex.

Comment: when you compile on overleaf it should generate also a bbl. Check the auxiliary files.

Comment: I have checked on overleaf, before downloading the project. I have files jpeg, one file README.md, arXiv.sty (for the template), one file .text and one file .bib . Where can I find the bbl file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the bbl if you view logs

[image]

and then use the "other logs and files" dropdown:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ulrike Fischer. Let's see if it fix the issue.

Comment: Working like a charm! Thanks