# submission contained main.bib and no associated main.tex file

Tags: arxiv, bbl

I am trying to submit to `arxiv` and facing this error[image: this].

I have the `.bbl` file in my folder structure. I cannot seem to find the reason of this error. Also, what are `.rels` files, these are not created by me. I also saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588430/no-bbl-file-for-submission-to-arxiv) solution, and tried. It shows `output.bbl` in the logs. Do I add this in the main folder structure?

[image: bbl]

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a tex problem at all, but this is caused by arXiv decompressing the `.xlsx` file you've included (see arXiv's help page regarding ancillary files for [instructions on including them](https://info.arxiv.org/help/ancillary_files.html)).

The hidden files error is based on the how the files were unpacked from the `.xlsx` file by the uploading scripts. You should [report these errors](https://info.arxiv.org/help/contact.html) to arXiv's technical support team, as the unpacking of the `.xlsx` file is a known bug that has yet to be corrected. You may need to have the Editorial support team add the file for you as an ancillary file if you wish to make it available to your readers.